# How can I access multiple columns in Pandas 0.15 DataFrame.resample method?

Tags: pandas

In Pandas 0.12, if you used the resample method on a DataFrame with a custom resampling function, it would make one call per dataframe row to the custom function, giving access to the values in all columns. In Pandas 0.15, the resample method calls my custom function once per dataframe entry, and the only available value is that entry (not the entire row).

**How can I recover the 0.12 behavior and see the entire row in my custom function?**

Here's the difference:

Initial setup:

```
In [1]: import pandas

In [2]: import datetime

In [3]: import sys

In [4]: dt = datetime.datetime(2014,1,1)

In [5]: idx = [dt + datetime.timedelta(days=i) for i in [0,2]]

In [6]: df = pandas.DataFrame({'a': [1.0, 2.0], 'b': ['x', 'y']}, index=idx)

In [7]: foo = lambda data: sys.stdout.write("***\n" + str(data) + "\n")
```

0.12 behavior (notice that there are 3 calls to foo):

```
In [8]: pandas.__version__
Out[8]: '0.12.0'

In [9]: df.resample(rule='D', how=foo, fill_method='ffill')
***
            a  b
2014-01-01  1  x
***
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
***
            a  b
2014-01-03  2  y
Out[9]: 
               a     b
2014-01-01  None  None
2014-01-02  None  None
2014-01-03  None  None
```

0.15 behavior (notice that there are 6 calls to foo):

```
In [8]: pandas.__version__
Out[8]: '0.15.0'

In [9]: df.resample(rule='D', how=foo, fill_method='ffill')
***
2014-01-01    1
Name: a, dtype: float64
***
Series([], name: a, dtype: float64)
***
2014-01-03    2
Name: a, dtype: float64
***
2014-01-01    x
Name: b, dtype: object
***
Series([], name: b, dtype: object)
***
2014-01-03    y
Name: b, dtype: object
Out[9]: 
             a     b
2014-01-01 NaN  None
2014-01-02 NaN  None
2014-01-03 NaN  None
```

Comment: well, the 0.12.0 behavior was wrong. It was presenting a mixed-dtype DataFrame which is basically useless for a generically defined function. Much more useful is a function which is passed separate dtypes. What are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the behavior changed, but think using a `TimeGrouper` and `groupby` can get you back to the old results, although will error out unless foo is given a return value.

```
In [496]: df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).apply(foo)
***
            a  b
2014-01-01  1  x
***
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a, b]
Index: []
***
            a  b
2014-01-03  2  y
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
.....
ValueError: All objects passed were None
```